Identifying functions that don't return
I'm working on an embedded system that has a System_Fail function that doesn't return.  The objective of this function is to place the device in a safe state, then do nothing until power is cycled:
void System_Fail(void)
{
   // Code to place device in safe state
   while (1)
   {
     ;
   }
}  

Is there a standard way to mark or identify that this function doesn't return?
Static analyzers and Unit Testing frameworks will believe that this function returns, especially when the function is defined in an external translation unit.
Example:
int main(void)
{
    System_Fail();
    printf("Error: Execution returned from System_Fail()\n");
    return 0;
}

Before the call to System_Fail(), I'd like to place a standard marker or identifier that can show that the System_Fail() function does not return.  The System_Fail() is called when a validation fails (so the code doesn't continue).
Static analysis tool are assuming that the System_Fail() function returns and generates errors and warnings because of this misunderstanding.
Unit Test fixtures believe the function returns and continue executing code that is from an invalid state.
Notes:

This is on an embedded system, using MicroCOS, an ARM-Cortex M4 based system.
Compiler is IAR Embedded Workbench.
Coverity is one of our static analysis tools.
Another example is starting (launching) an RTOS that never returns.


[[ noreturn ]] or one of its predecessors? _Noreturn System_Fail();

@Thomas Matthews In C You can use function specifier _Noreturn
.

I just took a dive in the IAR Embedded Workbench - Compiler Guide and realized that you probably can't use C11 or later so I added an option specifically for the compiler you use to the answer. I hope that will make C-STAT and Coverity quiet :-)

@Thomas Did you ever get this working?

My boss did a task  switch on me (I'm now on applications, C++ and MSVS).  When I get back to the embedded systems, I'll try it out.

You could give it the [[noreturn]] attribute which ...

Indicates that the function does not return.

[[noreturn]] void System_Fail();   // C23 attribute
_Noreturn void System_Fail(void);  // Function specifier since C11, prior to C23

From the C23 draft:

§ 6.7.5 Function specifiers

A function declared with a _Noreturn function specifier shall not return to its caller. The attribute [[noreturn]] provides similar semantics. The _Noreturn function specifier is an obsolescent
feature (6.7.13.7).

6.7.13.7 The noreturn and _Noreturn attributes

When _Noreturn is used as an attribute token (instead of a function specifier), the constraints and semantics are identical to that of the noreturn attribute token. Use of _Noreturn as an attribute token is an obsolescent feature
The noreturn attribute shall be applied to a function. No attribute argument clause shall be present.
The first declaration of a function shall specify the noreturn attribute if any declaration of that function specifies the noreturn attribute. If a function is declared with the noreturn attribute in
one translation unit and the same function is declared without the noreturn attribute in another translation unit, the behavior is undefined.
If a function f is called where f was previously declared with the noreturn attribute and f eventually returns, the behavior is undefined.
The __has_c_attribute conditional inclusion expression (6.10.2) shall return the value 202311L when given noreturn as the pp-tokens operand if the implementation supports the attribute.
The implementation should produce a diagnostic message for a function declared with a noreturn attribute that appears to be capable of returning to its caller.


The _Noreturn function specifier is also available via a convenience macro named noreturn if you #include <stdnoreturn.h>.

From the IAR Embedded Workbench - Compiler Guide:
The IAR C/C++ Compiler for AVR supports:

Standard C—also known as C99. Hereafter, this standard is referred to as Standard C in this guide.
C89—also known as C94, C90, C89, and ANSI C. This standard is required when MISRA C is enabled.

So, it does not support C11 or higher, but it has some extensions, one of which is:



__noreturn





Syntax
See Syntax for object attributes, page 298.


Description
The __noreturn keyword can be used on a function to inform the compiler that the function will not return. If you use this keyword on such functions, the compiler can optimize more efficiently. Examples of functions that do not return are abort and exit.Note: At optimization levels medium or high, the __noreturn keyword might cause incorrect call stack debug information at any point where it can be determined that the current function cannot return.


Example
__noreturn void terminate(void);



Since they have chosen to name the function specifier __noreturn instead of _Noreturn, you could create your own convenience macro
// nonstdnoreturn.h
#ifndef NONSTDNORETURN_H_CC001EB0_F1FA_11EE_8B54_90B11C0C0FF8
#define NONSTDNORETURN_H_CC001EB0_F1FA_11EE_8B54_90B11C0C0FF8
#define noreturn __noreturn
#endif

and use that noreturn macro until the day comes when you upgrade to C11 or later. You'd then search-and-replace all "nonstdnoreturn.h" with <stdnoreturn.h> - or just use __noreturn for now.
